# SMTP issue "Cannot connect to SMTP host DOMAIN.XXX.LOCAL."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, smtp

I am a newbie and trying to set up an alert via SharePoint 2013.

I have configured the SMTP at the domain server (`DOMAIN.XXX.LOCAL`) successfully. I know the SMTP is working because the email can be sent when I create a test TXT file and drop it into PICK UP folder of the MailRoot.

SharePoint 2013 is installed on `SP.XXX.LOCAL`. In the "Outbound SMTP Server" of Central Administration, I enter `DOMAIN.XXX.LOCAL`. There is no email sent after I set up the alert. I see the error "Cannot connect to SMTP host `DOMAIN.XXX.LOCAL`." in the Windows Event log.

I am not sure if I miss something. Please help.

Comment: Please let us know what SMTP service you're using (IIS6 SMTP, hMailServer, Exchange, etc.). Did you verify firewalls are not an issue (TCP/25 is open) and that servers, such as SP.XXX.LOCAL are allowed to relay to that SMTP server?

Comment: i have the same issue using iis6 smtp